# Someone Without The Right Role Using The Command Crashes The Bot discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, roles

Im trying this

> ```
> @commands.has_role("Buying/Selling Support")
> @bot.hybrid_command(name="cookie_recipe", description="Sends Cookie  Recipe")
>
> async def cookie_recipe(ctx):
>    await ctx.send("Currently Uploading...")
>    file = (discord.File("SHOP/src/cookie_recipe.txt"))
>    await ctx.send(file=file)
> ```

and it works fine when someone with the right role aka ("Buying/Selling Support") uses it but as soon as anyone who doesnt have that role uses it it gets an error "discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRole: Role 'Buying/Selling Support' is required to run this command."

HELP

ive looked through everything on stack overflow and asked a few friends and none of them know either

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you need to handle errors in Python you use the [`try/except` block](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) to avoid crashing. But if I guess correctly you are using discord.py then you should check the documentation on [how to handle errors](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#error-handling) and [Checks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#checks).

Also read the [documentation on `commands.has_role()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.has_role), it says:

> This check raises one of two special exceptions, [MissingRole](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.MissingRole) if the user is missing a role, or [NoPrivateMessage](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.NoPrivateMessage) if it is used in a private message. Both inherit from [CheckFailure](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CheckFailure).

According to the documentation to handle error when a user uses the command without having the correct role, you should create a function to handle it. In this case, we use `CheckFailure` to handle both possible errors and avoid creashing the bot.

```
@commands.has_role("Buying/Selling Support")
@bot.hybrid_command(name="cookie_recipe", description="Sends Cookie  Recipe")

async def cookie_recipe(ctx):
   await ctx.send("Currently Uploading...")
   file = (discord.File("SHOP/src/cookie_recipe.txt"))
   await ctx.send(file=file)


@cookie_recipe.error
async def cookie_recipe_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("You don't have the correct role or sent a private message.")
```